# Is there a way to upload/zip an entire anaconda environment and recreate it using anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a working anaconda environment for a project which I am developing a script/pipeline with. I am now trying to share this environment with my team. Unfortunately when trying to recreate the environment using an exported yml file (ie `conda env export > environment.yml` and then `conda env create -f environment.yml` on a new machine ) it does not work anymore because the package versions I used when initially creating the env a few months ago are now listed as 'broken' on conda-forge or bioconda. This is causing the entire env create to fail with broken dependencies. I have tried manually editing the yml file to known 'unbroken' versions, but this causes lots of other dependency issues and the env still fails to be created.

Is there a way I can share/upload the working local environment to anaconda using anaconda-build, not just one package? Essentially take a list of all installed packages in the environment and then create a new package that others can install using anaconda cloud.